# Enable Browser Caching in Wordpress using .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I attempted to update the .htaccess file in my wordpress root directory, but it still doesn't appear to be working properly because when I run [my site](http://www.dellwoodbrewing.chrispiccini.com) through [googles page speed test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) the test results indicate that I should consider caching certain jpegs being loaded to that page.

This is my .htaccess file after making modifications.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Expire
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</Filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
# End Expire
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This would be more on-topic on the Pro Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by enabling the expires module.

```
a2enmod expires
```

Then restarted Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: If you had removed the `<IfModule>` wrapper you would have gotten an appropriate error. The `<IfModule>` wrappers are generally only required if you have some module dependency (you don't) or it is intended to work on multiple servers where this module might not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like it should work, although for one of my sites I use configuration as follows, give it a try:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 months"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 7 days"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 minutes"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 10 minutes"
</ifModule>
```

Have you checked if mod_expires is actually working - maybe that's the problem?